# Using list as a key for list

Tags: r

Is it anyhow possible to use list as a key for a list? I'd like something as below to work:

```
lst <- list()
lst[[ list("a", 1:2) ]] <- list(name = "first item", id = 1)
## Error in lst[[list("a", 1:2)]] <- list(name = "first item", id = 1) : 
##  invalid subscript type 'list'
```

The idea is to create a lookup table with list keys. The simple solution is to use hashes as keys (e.g. `fastdigest`), but I am wondering if there is no any direct solution for this?

Example:

```
lst <- list()
lst[[ list(V1 = "a",  V2 = 1:2, V3 = NULL) ]] <- list(name = "first item", id = 1)
lst[[ list(V1 = "a", V2 = 1:2, V3 = "lorem ipsum") ]] <- list(name = "second item", id = 2)
lst[[ list(V1 = "b", V2 = 3, V3 = "") ]] <- list(name = "third item", id = 3)

# calling it:
lst[[ list(V1 = "b", V2 = 3, V3 = "") ]]
## list(name = "third item", id = 3)
```

The basic problem with using hashes is that I would like also to be able to back-transform this data structure to  "flat" list, e.g.

```
list(V1 = "a",  V2 = 1:2, V3 = NULL, name = "first item", id = 1)
```

and with hashes, for doing this I would need to store the key-hash dictionary separately to be able to re-create them etc. It would also need defining my own, pretty complicated, classes and methods for accessing them. So I'm asking if there is no direct solution, i.e. using lists as keys?

Comment: @Dason I want to pack in lists the complicated data structures using complicated keys. Basically, the "better way" is to use hashes, but I am wondering if it is possible to bypass using hashes.

Comment: @Dason when using hashes I'd need to define some kind of data structure for for my data, I'm asking about list-keys since they would make it possible to take the data as-it-comes without any transformations needed.

Comment: @Dason OK, later on I'll edit to add more examples

Comment: Alright. Can you ping me when you get around to it so I get a reminder to check this out once its updated? Thanks. I'm gonna delete my other comments now.

Comment: @Dason you asked to ping you, so FYI, I edited my question.